# how to get a smartclient example on the web?

Tags: database, web-applications, smartclient

I'm pretty much totally lost.. I've posted twice on the smartclient forums and gotten no help so maybe the people here are more friendly than their own staff. (it really bothers me but they appear to have the best software for what I'm trying to do)

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I would get one of their examples (the demo showcase ones which I have downloaded etc) on my web host, just to see how it works/play with it, but I couldn't find any forum guides or videos etc on this (documentation is really abysmal for people that don't speak code yet).

Is there some special back-end I need on my web host? Where can I go to figure out how to link the stuff together? Do I have to compile something using java.. etc.
I'm used to just editing stuff in notepad++, uploading it, and hitting refresh, but I'm guessing smartclient isn't that simple, or is it? (I'm just going to use it to make tables from excel spreadsheets that I can filter through, that's it, no fancy application).

Sincerely,
Mr. Totally Lost.

Comment: What does it looks like (the *thing* you have downloaded) ?

Comment: @Jean-Michel Garcia I downloaded the entire smartclient enterprise package, it contains all the smartclient examples, I'm interested in getting any one of them on my own webhost so I can atleast understand what the process is. I have no idea if you have to set up stuff in phpmyadmin, or do something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is covered by the guide (page 6) : http://www.smartclient.com/docs/8.2/docs/SmartClient_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf

SmartClient embed everything needed, you will only need a valid JDK installation and the zip provided in their website.